# How to find P(X>Y) for a discrete joint PDF?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have to find P(X>Y) for the below Joint PDF.

$$ P(X=x,Y=y) = \frac{x+y}{12},\space x=1,2;\space\space\space y=1,2; $$

I tried as follows,

$$ P(X>Y)= \frac{2+1}{12}=3/12=1/4 $$
$$P(X+Y\le3) = \frac{1+2}{12}+\frac{2+1}{12}+\frac{1+1}{12}=8/12 $$

I don't know whether or not my answers -- and also steps -- are correct.

Comment: Where does 'PDF' come from in discrete distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X,Y$ are both random variables that only take values in $\{1,2\}$ then $\{X>Y\}=\{X=2, Y=1\}$ so that $$P(\{X>Y\})=P(X=2,Y=1)=\frac{2+1}{12}=\frac14$$
So you did that correctly.

It is not clear to me why you also (correctly) calculated $P(X+Y\leq 3)$.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation of $P(X> Y)$ is correct. To obtain the probability of the sum you can make a table

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline Y \backslash X &1&2& \sum \\ \hline 1&\frac2{12} & \frac3{12} &\frac5{12} \\ \hline 2&\frac3{12}&\frac4{12} &\frac7{12} \\ \hline \sum &  \frac5{12} & \frac7{12} &1 \\ \hline\end{array}$$ is

Now it is obvious that $X+Y=Z$ has the possible outcomes $1,3$ and $4$

The corresponing pdf is

$$f_{X+Y}(z)=\begin{cases} \frac2{12}, \ z=2 \\ \frac6{12}, \ z=3 \\  \frac4{12}, \ z=4 \\  0, \ \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

I´m sure you can take it from here.

**Remark:**

I´ve noticed that your calculation and result for $P(X+Y\leq 3)$ is correct as well.